# How to auto focus on the last focused element in Google Chrome debug tools after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, refresh, developer-tools

In Google Chrome, there is the native behavior that if you have an element focused in the developer tools `Elements` tab and then did a page refresh - it resumes focus on that element when the page reloads; albeit only for pages that have their content delivered with the initial page download.

[image: Elements in dev tools]

It does not do this when working with front-end framework scripts such as `Angular`, `ReactJS`, `VueJS`, etc.

Is there a way to get this behavior replicated in pages that load the content after the page load (ie: not sent with the HTML page when downloaded)

I was hoping there might be some buried setting or configuration somewhere that I am not aware of.